# awk copy field data to new field

Tags: linux, csv, awk

How do I copy using / as field delimiter values to the end of the line using , as the delimiter?

I have a file that has something like this in it:

```
/folder/subfolder1/user1/1234/file.jpg,2014-11-24 11:49:55.6590447890 +0200
/folder/subfolder1/user2/ddaa/file.jpg,2014-11-24 11:49:55.6590447890 +0200
/folder/subfolder1/user2/sssffd/file.jpg,2014-11-24 11:43:03.6438296240 +0200
/folder/subfolder1/user3/882ssa/file.jpg,2014-11-24 11:43:00.6918628210 +0200
```

and what I need as an output would be:

```
/folder/subfolder1/user1/1234/file.jpg,2014-11-24 11:49:55.6590447890 +0200,1234,1234 2014-11-24 11:49:55.6590447890 +0200,user1
/folder/subfolder1/user2/ddaa/file.jpg,2014-11-24 11:49:55.6590447890 +0200,ddaa,ddaa 2014-11-24 11:49:55.6590447890 +0200,user2
/folder/subfolder1/user2/sssffd/file.jpg,2014-11-24 11:43:03.6438296240 +0200,sssffd,sssffd 2014-11-24 11:49:55.6590447890 +0200,user2
/folder/subfolder1/user3/882ssa/file.jpg,2014-11-24 11:43:00.6918628210 +0200,882ssa,882ssa 2014-11-24 11:49:55.6590447890 +0200,user3
```

So I need to copy some parts of the line to the end of it and also put together a few fields as one.

Comment: split the first field into an array using `split(string,array,sep)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$ awk -F[/,] '{$0=$0","$5","$5" "$7","$4}1' input
/folder/subfolder1/user1/1234/file.jpg,2014-11-24 11:49:55.6590447890 +0200,1234,1234 2014-11-24 11:49:55.6590447890 +0200,user1
/folder/subfolder1/user2/ddaa/file.jpg,2014-11-24 11:49:55.6590447890 +0200,ddaa,ddaa 2014-11-24 11:49:55.6590447890 +0200,user2
/folder/subfolder1/user2/sssffd/file.jpg,2014-11-24 11:43:03.6438296240 +0200,sssffd,sssffd 2014-11-24 11:43:03.6438296240 +0200,user2
/folder/subfolder1/user3/882ssa/file.jpg,2014-11-24 11:43:00.6918628210 +0200,882ssa,882ssa 2014-11-24 11:43:00.6918628210 +0200,user3
```

Comment: That's close, but you have an additional `file.jpg,` in there.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Missed that. Corrected in answer :)

Comment: What does the `1` do following the `{expr-list}`, e.g. `{expr-list}1`. I'm curious and I've been picking though `man awk` and can't find a reference to a constant following `{expr-list}`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin here `1` evaluates true for each line. Since no `{action}` part is specified, it takes the default action to print the entire record, `$0` which we just modified. This is inturn a short hand for writing `{print $0}`. Hope my explantion is clear

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin so a longer format would look like `{$0=$0","$5","$5" "$7","$4} {print $0}`

Comment: Thank you, that is just what I needed. Learning occurred.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You are always welcome. Glad that i could help :)

Comment: Thank you very much nu11p01n73R and others that contributed. It worked just a I need it to work. I learned a lot and saved a lot of time :)